# Mojo Messaging Service - Device URL

Tags: palm-pre, mojo, mojo-sdk

Does anyone know the URL for using the Mojo messaging service with the device.  I can get it to work with the emulator from Google App Engine and .NET but it does not work on the device.  I've read in some other forums that it may be related to the URL.

Anyone have any information.  The URL I am currently using is https://ps15.sb.palm.com/palmcsext/services/deviceJ/publish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the docs http://developer.palm.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1671 :

> The Mojo Messaging service is
>   currently in beta and is not yet
>   available for production deployments.
>   Developers with apps nearing readiness
>   should contact Palm developer support
>   to inquire about deploying as part of
>   the beta program.

This means that it only works on the emulator because its running a developer version of the ROM for beta testing - against developer/beta servers.  There is not currently a developer ROM available for the devices, so you can test this on the devices at the moment.  The production ROM runs against different messaging servers that are not available .. yet.